# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException reverse

Tags: java

I'm writing a code to reverse a substrungs in a string. For example:
Hello world
result: olleH dlrow

```
public class q05 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String str= sc.nextLine();
     int length = 0,beginString=0,j=0,i=0;
     String reversedString=new String();

   while(length<str.length()){   //check all the string

       for(i=0;str.charAt(i)!= ' ';i++){
        j++;
       }
      String subString= str.substring(beginString, j); // create substring
      String reversedsubString=new String();  // create the blank substring
      System.out.println(subString);

      while(j>=0){    // reverse the substring

          reversedsubString=reversedsubString+subString.charAt(j);
          j--;


      }


      reversedString=reversedString+reversedsubString;
      System.out.println(reversedString);
      i++;
      length++;
      }

   System.out.println(reversedString);

}
```

It gives me an error of: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Note for your future self: when you get an exception and ask about it on SO you should post the strack trace as well.

Comment: One quick observation: `for(i=0;str.charAt(i)!= ' ';i++)` - when do you think that loop will stop for strings that don't contain space characters? Hint: at `i == str.length()`. And now guess how it will stop ... you're right, with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Another note: string concatenation can use up quite a lot of memory since the system will create a new string for each `a+b`. Better use a `StringBuilder` anlong with it's `append()` methods. Btw, `StringBuilder` also has a `reverse()` method, so splitting your input and reversing the individual parts might do the trick :)

Comment: Instead of `for(i=0;str.charAt(i)!= ' ';i++){
        j++;
       }
      String subString= str.substring(beginString, j);` why don't you just use `str.split(" ")`?

Comment: @QBrute I hadn't learn it yet.

Comment: @Thomas So how I need to write the for loop

Comment: I think you got too many loops. The outermost while loop loops over the entire string (11 times for “Hello world”). Each time the for loops tries to find the first space char — you don’t want to find that space 11 times. I think you’re better off getting your overall logic right before finding the right way to mend your StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Maybe `if (str.charAt(length) == ' ') {` … `}`. Inside the if statement, find the substring to the left of the space and reverse it. Add the reversed substring to `reversedString` and then add the space. Remember to record the location of the space so that if you find another space you know where the word began. Finally, after the outer loop terminates, reverse the last word and add it to the result.

Comment: Also, in your inner while loop you have a substring that you know is `j` characters long. You start by taking `subString.charAt(j)`, but the indices in the string are `0` through `j - 1`. I believe this is the source for your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify efficiency limitations, this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String input = "Hello world";


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = input.split(" ");


    for (String word : words) {

        // Second word on
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(reverse(word));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

public static String reverse(final String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Run from end to start
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can I do this without split?

Comment: You can. Are you thinking you will hand in an answer from Stackoverflow as your solution to your homework?

Comment: Note that `sb.append( reverse(word) )` could be replaced by `s.append( new StringBuilder(word).reverse() )`, i.e. you don't need to provide your own reverse method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         String str= sc.nextLine();
         StringBuilder reverseWords = new StringBuilder();
         String[] words = str.split("\\s+");   // space(s) are the delimiters

         for (String word : words) { //fetch a single word from inputted sentence
             char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
             int end = word.length() - 1;//length of word

             StringBuilder revWords = new StringBuilder();
             for (int i = end; i >= 0; i--) {//start the loop from end to get the last char from words 
                 revWords.append(charArray[ i]);//add the last char of word into stringbuilder
             }
             reverseWords.append(revWords);
             reverseWords.append(" ");     // separate the words
         }
         System.out.print(reverseWords);
        }
```